# How to query the documents from couchdb and load them into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, csv, nosql, couchdb

I have downloaded Twitter data on local couchdb server.
And it was saved as json files.

I use this code to enter the database in python.
1st import libraries

```
import couchdb
import pandas as pd
from couchdbkit import Server
import json
import cloudant
```

next connect to server and choose the database I want to enter.

```
dbname = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')
db = dbname['Test']
server = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')
```

I could create and delete databases with python however, I don't know how I can put the data from the server to jupyter notebook.
I would like to get the text and time with retweets to analyze it.
I can only see one JSON file from python.

If possible I would like to add the all JSON data in the db to pandas dataframe in python so I can analyze it in R too.

The question is: How to query the documents and load them into pandas dataframe?

Comment: What is question here? You want to dump couch docs to CSV? You want to query the documents and load them into pandas dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for comment. How to query the documents and load them into pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the documents from a CouchDB's database can be pulled from [`/{db}/_all_docs`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs) end-point with `include_docs` query attribute. The response is a json object where all the docs listed in `rows` field.

You can either use `requests` package to work with CouchDB directly and then load the response into pandas with `pandas.read_json` or use `couchdb` package that translates json into python objects internally and then load the response directly, i.e. do something like this:

```
import couchdb
import pandas as pd

couch = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')
db = couch['Test']
rows = db.view('_all_docs', include_docs=True)
data = [row['doc'] for row in rows]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Please be aware than reading a complete database into memory could be resource taxing, so you might want to look into `skip` and `limit` query parameters of `_all_docs` end-point to read information in smaller batches.

Comment: I was able to load the json in as data frame on pandas as you suggested. One thing, inside the json is an other json file with dictionaries inside it. example. column name is entities and inside it`{u'symbols': [], u'user_mentions': [{u'indices': [0, 14], u'id': 305734622, u'id_str': u'305734622', u'name': u'Charles Watts', u'screen_name': u'name_'}, {u'indices': [15, 24], u'id': 845149392, u'id_str': u'845149392', u'name': u'name_', u'screen_name': name'}], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}` How can I add these too as dataframe?

Comment: It depends on a structure of dataframe you want to get at the end. Pandas' dataframe is two-dimensional structure, so you need to transform `row['doc']` to desired shape while looping through `rows` before passing resulted `data` to pandas.

Comment: can you explain the _'doc'_ meaning?

Comment: Row's 'doc' is a single database document, a representation of a single tweet in your case, converted from original json into python object.